# How might one create a nice looking table in Latex?

Tags: tables

I am able to create a table that looks bland. I am wondering how to create tables like the one below: [image]

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Variable Descriptions}
\label{tab:2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
Variables & Descriptions\\\hline
\textit{ln(wage)} & log of wage\\
\textit{educ} & years of education\\
\textit{black} & 1 if black and 0 if not\\
\textit{hisp} & 1 if hispanic and 0 if not\\
\textit{exper} & years of experience\\
\textit{exper$^{2}$} & years of experience squared\\
\textit{married} & 1 if married and 0 if not\\
\textit{union} & 1 if belongs to a union and 0 if not\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The particular question is:

- How might one alternate row colours between grey and white? Is there a way to create a command rather than colouring them manually?

Comment: In order to alternatingly color rows in a table, take a look at the `\rowcolors` command which is defined when using `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`

Comment: Adding `\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}` to the preamble and using `\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray} ` right before `\begin{tabular}` should give you the desired result.

Comment: I recommend to check out booktabs package to enhance the quality of tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are three versions of your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor} % provides the \rowcolors command 
\usepackage{caption} % for improved spacing around the caption

\usepackage{array} % enables >{...} in the coumn specifier section, used in table 2 & 3
\usepackage{booktabs} % for improved spacing around horizontal lines, used in example 3, incompatible with vertical lines, be careful if you want to to combine it with color

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace} % for adding a small amount of space above and below each cell, only used in table 2
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Variable Descriptions}
\label{tab:2}
\centering % used \centering instead of the center environment since the latter adds additional white space
\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
Variables & Descriptions\\\hline
\textit{ln(wage)} & log of wage\\
\textit{educ} & years of education\\
\textit{black} & 1 if black and 0 if not\\
\textit{hisp} & 1 if hispanic and 0 if not\\
\textit{exper} & years of experience\\
\textit{exper$^{2}$} & years of experience squared\\
\textit{married} & 1 if married and 0 if not\\
\textit{union} & 1 if belongs to a union and 0 if not\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Variable Descriptions}
\label{tab:2}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray} 
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}0l0l}\hline % used >{\itshape} in order to be able to remove the repeated occurences of \textit in the first column, used l type columns instead of c columns for a cleaner look, added small vertical space above and below the rows with the help of the cellspace package, removed all vertical lines
\textup{Variables}       & Descriptions\\\hline
ln(wage)                 & log of wage\\
educ                     & years of education\\
black                    & 1 if black and 0 if not\\
hisp                     & 1 if hispanic and 0 if not\\
exper                    & years of experience\\
exper\textsuperscript{2} & years of experience squared\\
married                  & 1 if married and 0 if not\\
union                    & 1 if belongs to a union and 0 if not\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Variable Descriptions}
\label{tab:2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}ll}
\toprule % replaced all \hline commands with rules from the booktabs package
\textup{Variables}       & Descriptions\\
\midrule
ln(wage)                 & log of wage\\
educ                     & years of education\\
black                    & 1 if black and 0 if not\\
hisp                     & 1 if hispanic and 0 if not\\
exper                    & years of experience\\
exper\textsuperscript{2} & years of experience squared\\
married                  & 1 if married and 0 if not\\
union                    & 1 if belongs to a union and 0 if not\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I will answer the core of your question: `I am wondering how to create tables like this.`

I work with tables all the time, from experiments results to monthly budgets. For tasks like sorting, formatting, checking, and simple data analysis, I do it in Excel (using 2013).
The final table will eventually come out after many iterations and time.

In your example is clear that the data come out of a database, there will be vertical accumulated results of all patches and all fixes, cross checking for consistency, etc.

LaTeX is for publishing beautiful reports, but this happens a few times a year. Only in very simple tables can the data be written directly to LaTeX.

My Excel to LaTeX workflow has 3 steps:

1 Format the final table with the style you need, in Excel. Use colors, rulers, etc., as needed.

[image: side by side]

2. Export the table using CTAN's Excel2Latex add-in. It is easy to install and works as advertised.

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex?lang=en

copy to clipboard and paste it into a basic LaTeX document.

[image: coy to clipboard]

You need to add some basic packages (see my example) and run the resulting code.

You will see that most of the features like multi-row, colors, and most importantly, the content was successfully passed to LaTeX.
If you change your mind about a detail in the style, it's easy to edit the Excel sheet and regenerate the LaTeX code.

3 Apply the finishing touches: fonts, stretch, hyphens, symbols, etc. using LaTeX commands.

For your example, I included the `caption` package to match the original caption,  added the superscripts in the first row, the undeline in the second, and the small caps as needed. I used `arraystretch` from 1.3 to expand the cell vertically.

In this particular case, I had to include a 7 point offset down in a double gray row, to prevent the bottom cell background from overwriting part of the cell content. This is a common occurrence when working with colored cells. Comment  `[7pt]` and see what happens.

Of course everything will come out looking good if you use only one background color! But I found the alternate row color style to be very nice and a must with wide multi-column tables. Beamer presentations will be doomed if you use only black and white.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{multirow}

\RequirePackage{caption}% typesetting of captions
\captionsetup{%
    labelfont={bf}, %Table 1
    textfont={bf}  %caption font
}%

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % expand the rows vertically
    \setlength\belowcaptionskip{8pt}    
    \centering
    \caption{Test--suite based program repair tools for Java.}
    \begin{tabular}{llrrr}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Repear tool}} & Benchmark used & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\# Bugs}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\# Patched\textsuperscript{a}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\# Fixed\textsuperscript{b}} \\
        & in evaluation &       &       &  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\underline{\emph{Generate--and--validate}}} \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902} ACS [4] & Defects4J & 224   & 23    & 17 \\
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{ARJA [50]} & Defects4J & 224   & 59    & 18 \\
        & QuixBugs [48] & 40    & 4     & 2 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902} \multirow{2}[1]{*}{\textsc{CapGen} [42]}  & Defects4J & 224   & 25    & 22 \\[7pt] % shift needed for colored multirows
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}     & IntroClassJava & 297   & --    & 25 \\
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{Cardumen [28]} & Defects4J & 356   & 77    & -- \\
        & QuixBugs [48] & 40    & 5     & 3 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902} DeepRepair [43] & Defects4J & 374   & 51    & -- \\
        \multirow{2}[0]{*}{\textsc{Elixir} [37]} & Defects4J & 82    & 41    & 26 \\
        & Bugs.jar & 127   & 39    & 22 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902} GenProg-A & Defects4J & 224   & 36    & -- \\
        HDRepair [18] & Defects4J & 90    & --    & 23 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}\textsc{Jaid} [2] & Defects4J & 138   & 31    & 25 \\
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{jGenProg [27]} & Defects4J & 224   & 29    & -- \\
        & Defects4J [26] & 224   & 27    & 5 \\
        & QuixBugs [48] & 40    & 2     & 0 \\
        \ldots  & \ldots & \ldots    & \ldots    & \ldots \\ % more rows follows
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{a} As reported last week. \ \textsuperscript{b} Verified by QC. }\\
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

This is the final result. Total time 1-2 hour, mostly in data entry and formatting the sheet.
[image: a nice table]

As a final exercise, try adding another column to the table asked by your boss just before the deadline: `Still Missing` with the data (calculated in the excel sheet) that is `Bugs` minus `Patches` minus `Fixed` and see how it all works (and how little time it takes!). A real world situation.

Answer (score 5):

Remark: **This answer needs the version 5.2 (2020-08-19) of `nicematrix`.**

The image given by the OP shows rows alternately colored. But some rows are in fact the reunion of several rows. In this condition, it's difficult to use `\rowcolors` of `xcolor`.
In the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.2 of 2020-08-19), the built-in instruction `\rowcolors` (to be used in `code-before`) has an option `respect-blocks` to deal with that problem. The rows encompassing a block are considered as only one row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NiceMatrixOptions{notes = { para , style = \alph{#1} } }

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ll@{\space}lrrr}%
 [ code-before = \rowcolors{3}{gray!20}{}[respect-blocks] ]
\toprule
Repair tool & 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\makecell[l]{Benchmark used\\ in evaluation}} 
& 
\# Bugs &
\# Patched\tabularnote{Note}& 
\# Fixed\tabularnote{Note}\\
\midrule
\underline{\emph{Generate-and-validate}} \\
ACS [46] & Defects4J & & 224 & 23 & 17 \\
\Block{2-1}{}\multirow{2}{*}{ARJA [50]} & Defects4J&  & 224 & 59 & 18 \\
& QuixBugs& [38] & 40 & 4 & 2 \\
\Block{2-1}{}\multirow{2}{*}{\textsc{CapGen} [42]} & Defects4J& & 224 & 25 & 22 \\
& \rlap{IntroClassJava} & & 297 & -- & 25 \\
\Block{2-1}{}\multirow{2}{*}{Cardumen [28]} & Defects4J& & 356 & 77 & -- \\
& QuixBugs& [48] & 40 & 5 & 3 \\
DeepRepair [43] & Defects4J& & 374 & 51 & - \\
\Block{2-1}{}\multirow{2}{*}{\textsc{Elixir} [37]} & Defects4J& & 82 & 41 & 26 \\
& Bugs.jar & & 127 & 39 & 22 \\
GenProg-1 [50] & Defects4J& & 224 & 36 & -- \\
HDRepair [18] & Defects4J& & 90 & -- & 23 \\
\textsc{Jaid} [2] & Defects4J& & 138 & 31 & 25 \\
\Block{3-1}{}\multirow{3}{*}{jGenProg [27]} & Defects4J & & 224 & 29 & -- \\
& Defects4J & [26] & 224 & 27 & 5 \\
& QuixBugs& [48] & 40 & 2 & 0 \\
\Block{3-1}{}\multirow{3}{*}{jKali [27]} & Defects4J& & 224 & 22 & -- \\
& Defects4J& [26] & 224 & 22 & 1 \\
& QuixBugs& [48] & 40 & 2 & 1 \\
\Block{2-1}{}\multirow{2}{*}{jMutRepair [27]} & Defects4J& & 224 & 17 & -- \\
& QuixBugs& [48] & 40 & 3 & 1 \\
Kali-A [50] & Defects4J& & 224 & 33 & -- \\
LSRepair [23] & Defects4J& & 395 & 38 & 19 \\
PAR [17] & \rlap{PARDataset} & & 119 & 27 & -- \\
\Block{2-1}{}\multirow{2}{*}{PSRepair-A [50]} & Defects4J& & 224 & 44 & -- \\
& QuixBugs& [48] & 40 & 4 & 2 \\
SimFix [14] & Defects4J& & 357 & 56 & 34 \\
\textsc{SketchFix} [13] & Defects4J& & 357 & 26 & 19 \\
SOFix [24] & Defects4J& & 224 & -- & 23 \\
ssFix [45] & Defects4J& & 357 & 60 & 20 \\
xPar [18] & Defects4J& & 90 & -- & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Just a simple comment: in the 2nd column is it possible to align vertically the numbers `[...]`?

Comment: @Sebastiano: Done! I have added a column.

Comment: My eyes, before, went to the left :-)...Now it is surely better.

Comment: @F. Pantigny Please edit your answer remarking the need to  install the latest version of ``nicematrix`` 2020/08/19 v5.2 in order to run te code successfully.
Up today (22-Aug-20) was available from CTAN but not in the mirrors. When I first run it (and getting a wrong output), two days ago, the previous version 5.1 was installed from MikTeX.

Just now, looking for [respect-blocks] in the manual I realized that my working version was not the 5.2.

Comment: @Simon Dispa: In fact, this question gave me the idea to add this key `respect-blocks` in my package `nicematrix`.

Comment: It's a good package. The strategy of painting the panels first and then adding the content solves many of the problems with colored cells.

Comment: @F. Pantigny Please correct 3.2 by 5.2 in the remark.

Comment: @Simon Dispa: Oups... Yes : 5.2. I've corrected.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one? (using `matrix` of TikZ)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,draw=teal,thick,inner sep=.5pt,
nodes in empty cells,
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
nodes={minimum height=9mm,anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes={font=\bfseries}},
column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=2.5cm,text width=1.5cm,align=left,font=\itshape}},
column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=7cm,text width=6cm,align=left}},
every even row/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!20}}
]{
Variables & Descriptions\\  
ln(wage)                 & log of wage\\
educ                     & years of education\\
black                    & 1 if black and 0 if not\\
hisp                     & 1 if hispanic and 0 if not\\
exper                    & years of experience\\
exper\textsuperscript{2} & years of experience squared\\
married                  & 1 if married and 0 if not\\
union                    & 1 if belongs to a union and 0 if not\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```